# parsley.js - manually display a message without having to validate

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I want to display a parsley message in an else clause of my javascript code:

```
if ( ...is valid ) {
    //do things
} else {
    //display parsley error
}
```

I know that Parsley allows custom validators as documented here: http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#javascript

But I merely want to display the message until the field is modified. I could create a validator such as:

```
$( '#myInput' ).parsley( {
    validators: {
      alwaysFalse: function ( val ) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  , messages: {
      myMessage: "Form is invalid"
    }
});
```

But then how would I trigger this and only this validator? (There is another validator already attached)

Comment: I am very much having the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your messages object should be a mirror of your validators object but with the messages to display.

```
messages: {
  alwaysFalse: "Form is invalid"
}
```

and you could try

```
validators: {
  alwaysFalse: function(val){
    return false;
  },
  required: function ( val ) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

also

> Warning : you must remove parsley-validate auto-binding code in your forms DOM to allow you to override the default processing and use Parsley purely from javascript.

it seems like what you really want this: http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#parsleyfield
check out parsley-error-container

the trigger should be `$( '#myInput' ).parsley( 'validate' );`

or not 100% sure on this but you should be able to call each one like this:

```
$( '#myInput' ).parsley('alwaysFalse');
```

and if they need inputs or data:

```
$( '#myInput' ).parsley('alwaysFalse','inputs','data');
```